# How to click on the tab button using Selenium Webdriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I will click that button in red circle.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNpo0.jpg)

and I would like to crawling that site.
How do I write python codes?

I tried this code and

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
url_base = 'https://www.kebhana.com/cont/mall/mall08/mall0805/index.jsp?_menuNo=62608'
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get(url_base)
openElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("li[2]")).click(); 


time.sleep(2)

openElement.click()
time.sleep(5)


driver.quit()
soup
```

the error message were appeared like this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-19b58965022a> in <module>()
      8 
      9 driver.get(url_base)
---> 10 openElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("li[2]")).click();
     11 
     12 

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'
```

and the html code of that button is

```
<li class="on">
   <a href="#none" onclick="javascript:doTab('spb_2812');">
      <span>적 금</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of a couple of things:

- As you are using *Selenium-Python* clients, `findElement()` is not a valid line of code. Instead you need to use either of the following:

  - `find_element_by_xpath()`
  - `find_element_by_css_selector()`
- `linkText` accepts only *text* only.
- Inducing `time.sleep(5)` will degrade the *Test Execution* performance.

---

### Solution

To `click()` on the element with text as **`적 금`**, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.productSearchDiv li:nth-child(2) >a>span"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='productSearchDiv ']//li/a/span[text()='적 금']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: kebhana]

Answer (score 0):

To click on the tab you need to induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()` and use below xapth.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.kebhana.com/cont/mall/mall08/mall0805/index.jsp?_menuNo=62608")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='productSDiv']//li//a[contains(@onclick,'spb_2812')]"))).click()
```

Comment: @fairystarlight : Glad to help you.Please accept the answer by clicking on hollow under downvote button so It will turn green.

Answer (score 0):

`findElement` is Java syntax, not Python. In addition, `li` is a tag, not text, and `by_link_text` doesn't work on `<span>` tags anyway.

Use `xpath` instead

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[.//span[.="적 금"]]')
```